# The image I tried to display via Flutter NetworkImage is not displayed correctly

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I apologize for the Korean language in the source code. I checked that the link is saved normally in firebase and delivered normally with the source code below.

```
                     {
                        print('');
                        print(card['info']['카드 이미지']);
                        print('');

                        return MissionCard(
                          logoPath: card['info']['카드 이미지'],
                          name: card['info']['카드 제목'],
                          description: card['info']['카드 설명'],
                          isRegistered: true,
                        );
                      }


...
...

      children: <Widget>[
            Image(
              image: NetworkImage(logoPath),
              height: 96,
              width: 96,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
```

I verified that the image link is passed through the print statement as shown in the screenshot below. I also verified that the displayed link is displayed correctly when opened in Chrome.

Screenshot confirming that the image link is returned correctly to the terminal

[image]

[This is the link.](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/samilgo.appspot.com/o/image%2F1680005913354%EB%8B%A4%EC%9A%B4%EB%A1%9C%EB%93%9C.jpg?alt=media&token=7c34e043-70c1-4db6-8f16-56ac0750331c)

However, the link I put in for testing, which returns a random image from the web, works fine, but my image link does not.

Screenshot capturing what it looks like

[image]

And it returns a message like the one below.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProgressEvent$ object was thrown resolving an image codec:
  [object ProgressEvent]

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

Image provider:
  NetworkImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/samilgo.appspot.com/o/image%2F1680005913354%EB%8B%A4%EC%9A%B4%EB%A1%9
  C%EB%93%9C.jpg?alt=media&token=7c34e043-70c1-4db6-8f16-56ac0750331c",
  scale: 1)
Image key:
  NetworkImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/samilgo.appspot.com/o/image%2F1680005913354%EB%8B%A4%EC%9A%B4%EB%A1%9
  C%EB%93%9C.jpg?alt=media&token=7c34e043-70c1-4db6-8f16-56ac0750331c",
  scale: 1)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Hopefully, the image will display normally.
Please Help me

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I have confirmed that this issue stems from a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) error. I have resolved the issue via the official documentation below.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

Comment: Can you give an example? I did `[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET"], "origin": ["*"]}]` and it didn't work

Comment: @Hssum how did you done this.

Comment: Please explain how this is a solution and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add

`<script type="text/javascript"> window.flutterWebRenderer = "html"; </script>`

To the index.html file of your Flutter project.

Flutter makes use of 2 rendering engines 'html' and 'CanvasKit'. By setting flutterWebRenderer to 'html' we manage to use a renderer that handles CORS policies a little more gracefully.